# Firebase extension on uninstall error message

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

I´m trying to uninstall a resize image firebase extension, but it's showing some error message:

`ext-storage-resize-images@zzz.iam.gserviceaccount.com","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/zzz/locations/us-central1/functions","httpMethod":"POST"}}`

[image]

## Firebase console logs

`{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Invalid function service account requested: ext-storage-resize-images@zzz.iam.gserviceaccount.com"},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"1072297581434@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com","serviceAccountDelegationInfo":[{"firstPartyPrincipal":{"principalEmail":"cloud-dm@prod.google.com"}}]},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"64.233.172.179","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"Google-Deployment-Manager,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2020-07-22T15:01:22.851Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction","authorizationInfo":[{"resource":"projects/zzz/locations/us-central1/functions/ext-storage-resize-images-generateResizedImage","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.create","granted":true,"resourceAttributes":{}}],"resourceName":"projects/zzz/locations/us-central1/functions/ext-storage-resize-images-generateResizedImage","request":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.CreateFunctionRequest","location":"projects/zzz/locations/us-central1","function":{"serviceAccountEmail":"ext-storage-resize-images@zzz.iam.gserviceaccount.com","eventTrigger":{"resource":"projects/_/buckets/zzz.appspot.com","eventType":"google.storage.object.finalize"},"runtime":"nodejs8","description":"Listens for new images uploaded to your specified Cloud Storage bucket, resizes the images, then stores the resized images in the same bucket. Optionally keeps or deletes the original images.","entryPoint":"generateResizedImage","sourceArchiveUrl":"gs://firebase-mod-sources-prod/a139bcfefbf19e901b67789105a3841ed208c6e449a896bafcc4a01e43c07844","availableMemoryMb":1024,"name":"projects/zzz/locations/us-central1/functions/ext-storage-resize-images-generateResizedImage","labels":{"deployment-tool":"firebase-extensions","goog-firebase-ext":"storage-resize-images","goog-firebase-ext-iid":"storage-resize-images"}}},"resourceLocation":{"currentLocations":["us-central1"]}}`

Comment: If you have feedback, bugs, or suggestions about extensions, file them on GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/extensions

Comment: @DougStevenson... ok... I´ll do that!